# Stash Regex Match

Tags: stash, regex

In my stash:get_list how would I ignore case sensitivity. I know its something to do with '/i' but don't know a thing about regex.

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="filter_list" match="#{stash:keyword}#" against="e_title"}
```

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a case insensitive modifier (?i) :

```
match="#(?i){stash:keyword}#"
```

(untested)

Comment: fantastic, thats the one. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

Without digging to deep I would look to transform your stash:set to lowercase to bypass testing. Something like streeng could remove cases and set to all lowercase for example.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/streeng

Comment: I'll be using the set values as normal case, so I'm not sure that would work, plus (I could be wrong), but I think the stash match and correct regex will work? I think something like match="#({stash:keyword})#i" is what I'm looking for, but just don't really get regex